# I keep getting Stack level too deep when trying to run tests for my project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

I am trying to run unit tests and integration tests for my project and each time I do with the code below, it passes except three and gives these errors

> Randomized with seed 29775
> ........FFF...
>
> Failures:
>
> 1. User Validations should have a name
>    Failure/Error: let(:new_user) { create(:user) }
>
>    SystemStackError:
>    stack level too deep
>
>    ## ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in '
>
>    ## ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in '
> 2. User Validations should be invalid without email
>    Failure/Error: let(:new_user) { create(:user) }
>
>    SystemStackError:
>    stack level too deep
>
>    ## ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in '
>
>    ## ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in '
> 3. User Validations should be invalid without name
>    Failure/Error: let(:new_user) { create(:user) }
>
>    SystemStackError:
>    stack level too deep
>
>    ## ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in '
>
>    ## ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 0.91935 seconds (files took 1.74 seconds to load) 14
> examples, 3 failures
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:13 # User Validations should have a
> name rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:24 # User Validations should be
> invalid without email rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:17 # User
> Validations should be invalid without name

Here are my factory files;

users.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user, aliases: %i[host event_attendee] do
    name { 'Joe' }
    email { "#{name}@email.com" }

    association :hosted_events, factory: :event
  end
end
```

events.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :event, aliases: [:hosted_events, :attended_events] do
    location { 'Freedom Park' }
    date { Faker::Date.between(from: 1.year.ago, to: 1.year.from_now) }
    description { 'wedding' }

    association :host, factory: :user
  end
end
```

user_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  let(:new_user) { create(:user) }

  describe 'Associations' do
    it { should have_many(:hosted_events) }
    it { should have_many(:attended_events) }
    it { should have_many(:event_attendances) }
  end

  describe 'Validations' do
    it 'should have a name' do
      expect(new_user).to be_valid
    end

    it 'should be invalid without name' do
      new_user.name = ''
      new_user.email = 'nil@example.com'

      expect(new_user).not_to be_valid
    end

    it 'should be invalid without email' do
      new_user.name = 'Joe'
      new_user.email = nil

      expect(new_user).not_to be_valid
    end
  end

  # pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
end
```

event_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Event, type: :model do
  describe 'Event Associations' do
    it { should belong_to(:host) }
    it { should have_many(:event_attendees) }
    it { should have_many(:event_attendances) }
  end

  describe 'Validations' do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:location) }
    it { should validate_presence_of(:date) }
    it { should validate_presence_of(:description) }
  end

  # pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
end
```

Comment: I believe that `association :hosted_events, factory: :event` then `association :host, factory: :user` is causing an infinite loop of creating events and hosts and events and hosts...

Comment: I noticed it too, but does it not need me to add any association to it?